# Making photo and text fit in two minipages

Tags: beamer, minipage

I have the following slide for my presentation and it is getting quite difficult to make the photo of the guy and the text to fit in. Actually, the text is appearing below that it should appear ( I want them to appear side by side).

```
\begin{frame}{Robin Milner (1934,2010)}
\scriptsize
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{milner.jpeg}
\end{minipage}
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
ACM A.M. Turing Award (1991). For three distinct and complete achievements:
    \begin{itemize}
    \item LCF, the mechanization of Scott's Logic of Computable Functions, probably the first theoretically based yet practical tool for machine assisted proof construction.
    \item ML, the first language to include polymorphic type inference together with a type-safe exception-handling mechanism.
    \item CCS, a general theory of concurrency.
    \end{itemize}

    In addition, he formulated and strongly advanced full abstraction, the study of the relationship between operational and denotational semantics. 
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
```

However I'm getting this result.

[image]

I already explored other questions in the site and didn't find a solution. What is that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the option in minipage from t to l and you will get the output.

```
    \documentclass{beamer}



    \begin{document}


    \begin{frame}{Robin Milner (1934,2010)}
    \scriptsize
    \noindent

    \begin{minipage}[l]{0.48\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{robin.jpg}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[l]{0.48\linewidth}
    ACM A.M. Turing Award (1991). For three distinct and complete achievements:
     \begin{itemize}
     \item LCF, the mechanization of Scott's Logic of Computable Functions, probably the first theoretically based yet practical tool for machine assisted proof construction.
     \item ML, the first language to include polymorphic type inference together with a type-safe exception-handling mechanism.
      \item CCS, a general theory of concurrency.
      \end{itemize}

       In addition, he formulated and strongly advanced full  abstraction, the study of the relationship between operational and denotational semantics. 
      \end{minipage}
       \end{frame}

       \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice duck!!!!!!

Comment: I thought this is @cfr.

Comment: Does not look like a duck anymore :(

Comment: Yes it looks no more  @samcarter

Answer (score 3):

With `columns` columns instead of `minipage`s:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Robin Milner (1934,2010)}
    \scriptsize
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth, T]
        \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{example-image-10x16}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
            ACM A.M. Turing Award (1991). For three distinct and complete achievements:
            \begin{itemize}
                \item LCF, the mechanization of Scott's Logic of Computable Functions, probably the first theoretically based yet practical tool for machine assisted proof construction.
                \item ML, the first language to include polymorphic type inference together with a type-safe exception-handling mechanism.
                \item CCS, a general theory of concurrency.
            \end{itemize}
            In addition, he formulated and strongly advanced full abstraction, the study of the relationship between operational and denotational semantics.
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]